# How do I add a List Item Action Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, related-list

I have 2 objects, A and B.

On Object B, I have added a quick action to update the record, and added it to the page layout, and can update records using Object B's layout in Salesforce1.

There is a related list for Object B on A's layout. When I view the related list records, I expect to be able to swipe on each record and see an Edit icon. But it doesn't show.

Is there anything special I need to do to show the List item action?

Cheers
Scott